# Getting form's parent data with ajax / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, dynamics-crm-2013

In CRM DYNAMICS 2013, I'm trying to get the contents of a few text fields of a parent form, after a user opens a child form.

On the OnLoad event of the child form, I have this code:

```
var objvsdsassignedto = document.parentWindow.parent.parent.opener.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("address1_line1");
```

The error I get is:

[image]

I have also tried:

```
var objvsdassignedto = window.top.opener.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_line1").getValue();
```

The error I get is:

[image]

**How do I get the contents of fields using the child form?**

[image]

here's a larger version of the screenshot above: http://screencast.com/t/KHrtREYn3tL

Just wanted to update this question with more of the things I've tried:

```
var objvsdsassignedto = window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("address1_line1").getValue();
var objvsdsassignedto = document.parentWindow.parent.parent.opener.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("address1_line1");
var objvsdsassignedto = window.top.opener.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_line1").getValue();
var objvsdsassignedto = parent.window.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("address1_line1").getValue();
var objvsdsassignedto = window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_composite");
var parentWindow = window.dialogArguments;
alert(  parentWindow.Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes('address1_composite').getValue());
var parentForm = window.top.opener.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_composite").getValue();
alert(parent.window.Xrm.Page.getAttribute('address1_line1').getValue());

var title = window.parent.opener.Xrm.page.ui.controls.getAttribute('address1_composite').getValue();
alert(title);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After around 10 hours of googling, I've decided to go with cookies: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you can't do that with a simple mapping in the relationship tab? At the end of the day you are creating a lead from an account, so if you want to move a field you should be able to do that via data mapping. Open the solution go into account open the N:1 relationship node, select the relationship to lead and add the fields you want to map, It should be fairly easy without using any js.
[image]

Comment: its a great idea but i dont always want this relationship to be present

Comment: Sorry for the generic answer, but i didn't used the quick creation much :) Just a note tho, a quick creation form should work with the same principle as a normal form, are you able to map the fields and apply the js logic after you move the fieds across? So using the normal Xrm.Page.GetAttribute() whitout trying to hack the html and get the values forbcibly ?